# $x y'=[x \sin(\frac{y}{x})]+y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So  I have to solve the homog. diff. equation $$xy'=\left[x \sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right]+y$$.
now,I know how to prove that it is a homogeneous diff equation of degree 0 ,so I won't write this one.

To the solution : $u=\frac yx$

$$y'=\frac{x\sin\left(\frac yx\right)+y}x$$ here $$u'x +u=\frac{x\sin\left(\frac{ux}x\right)+ux}x=\sin u+u$$
$$u'x=\sin u$$
$$\int \frac 1{\sin u}du=\int \frac 1x dx$$
$$\ln|\sin u|=\ln|xc|$$
$$\sin u=xc$$

When I replace $\;u=\frac yx$ I dont get $\;y=2\;x\arctan(c\,x)$ which is the answer in my book..why?

Comment: Could you clean up the presentation of your question?

Comment: what do you mean??

Comment: Use LaTeX better. I do not want to spend the effort to try to read the ASCII version of the question.

Comment: For a $\LaTeX$ primer, you can see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  If you must use text, please add some line breaks and be careful with parentheses.  Note the last $\ln |x*c|\sin u=x*c$ looks wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Everything was right up to :
$$\int \frac{du}{\sin(u)}=C+\int\frac{dx}x$$
Your error is in the integration at the left that should return :
 $$\ \log\left|\tan\left(\frac u2\right)\right|=C+\log|x|$$
Can you finish now?

Comment: Yes.thank you mate !

Comment: You are welcome @gnsf (btw I edited your question).